# UISlider and continuous property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am changing a value with `UISlider` and  this value is the number of my PDF pages , so when users sliding they can navigate through the pages , because of tiles rendering I need set `continuous` property to `NO`, also I need a live page counter that uses with the same slider, so the property should be `YES` :, how can I set the property yes or no for specific codes with the same slider ?

this part , the property should be  NO

```
navSlider.continuous = NO;
     pageInt = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfscroll.pdf);
     prgress = (int)(navSlider.value + 0.5);
    navSlider.maximumValue = pageInt;
    navSlider.minimumValue = 1;
    [bookController moveToPage:prgress];
```

and here yes :

```
navSlider.continuous = YES;
    NSString *numberOfPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",prgress,pageInt];
    pageCounter.text = numberOfPage;
```

Comment: @KaHole  I modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly *do* need to know about every slider change, so it must be continuous.  However, you should *not* call `[bookController moveToPage:prgress];` after every single slider movement.  The solution is to update the page number for every slider movement, but only call `[bookController moveToPage:prgress];` when the slider is released.